# Infinite while loop

Tags: python

Why is this while loop not ending when the proper input is entered (a number between 0 and 100)

```
grade = 110
invalid_input = 1
while grade< 0 or grade> 100:
    if invalid_input >=2:
        print "This is an invalid entry"
        print "Please enter a number between 0 and 100"
    grade= raw_input("Please enter your marks for Maths : ")
    invalid_input +=1
```

what ever i put in be it a number or text the (this is an invalid entry , Please enter a number between 0 and 100
does anyone one know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `grade=raw_input("Please enter your marks for Maths : ")`, `grade` is a string, not number. try

```
grade = int(raw_input("Please enter your marks for Maths : "))
```

In order to prevent the program from being terminated if the user makes a wrong input, you will need to use a [exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions), like this

```
grade = 110
invalid_input = 1
while grade< 0 or grade> 100:
    if invalid_input >=2:
        print "This is an invalid entry"
        print "Please enter a number between 0 and 100"
    try:
      grade= int(raw_input("Please enter your marks for Maths : "))
    except ValueError:
      grade = -1  # just to enter another iteration
    invalid_input +=1
```

Comment: the loop ends if i input a number but get a trace back error if i input text

Comment: This is the message i get
  converter.py", line 13, in <module>
    grade= int(raw_input("Please enter your marks for Maths : "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'the'

Comment: yes but i want the the message this is an invalid entry , Please enter a number between 0 and 100 does anyone one know what is wrong?

Comment: you'll need to use the try-catch construct. have a look at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions

Answer (score 2):

your `grade` should be cast to an int. Otherwise, since it's a string, the `while` condition will always remain satisfied.

Also, you can just as easily (and perhaps more cleanly) use a boolean for `invalid_input`:

```
invalid_input = True
while invalid_input:
    grade = int(raw_input("enter data"))
    if grade >= 0 and grade <= 100:
        invalid_input = False
    else:
        print "Please try again"
```

Comment: You can also do `if 0 <= grade <= 100:`